# Nested Xpath-predicates or not

Tags: xslt, xpath

**I'm wondering which Xpath expression is better?**

```
A[B/C]
```

vs

```
A[B[C]]
```

Are there any performance benefits for one or the other?

As a side note, it's clear to me that if B needs more filers (i.e. B needs a specific attribute) the second one should be used.

Comment: I think performance differences or benefits depend on the implementation. Some might show you an execution plan or rewrite they perform.

Comment: For instance, when I look with BaseX 9 at the rewrite of your both paths the result is exactly the same: `document { ... }/element(A)[element(B)/element(C)]` so your second approach is rewritten to your first. I can't tell whether that is something that then "works better" in only the BaseX implementation or in any case.

Comment: Readability of the code is also a factor of quality.

Comment: There's very unlikely to be a significant performance difference, but the only way to find out is to measure both.

Comment: @MartinHonnen: Thanks for the check in BaseX 9. I just did several performance-tests with different engines(Xalan, Saxon6.5.5, Saxon[HE|PE|EE] 9.9.1.5 all part of Oxygen 22). None gave noticeable performance differences.

Comment: @PierreFrançois: very true. I would say: choose one of the two and stick with that.